# Issue with REST API call from Python to Azure

Tags: python, json, azure, rest, api

I am using an HTML form to take in parameters to use for Azure REST API calls.

My Code

```
@app.route('/storageaccountcreate', methods = ['POST', 'PUT'])
def storageaccountcreate():
    name = request.form['storageaccountname']
    resourcegroup = request.form['resourcegroup']
    subscriptionId = request.form['subscriptionId']
    location = request.form['location']
    sku = request.form['sku']
    keys = [name, resourcegroup, subscriptionId, location, sku]
    api_json = {keys: request.form[key] for key in keys}
    url = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}?api-version=2019-06-01'
    r = requests.put((url),data=(api_json))
    print(r.text)
    return r.text
```

I am getting the following error when trying to use this code

```
Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Also the debugging in VSC is showing the following

[Photo of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Kna.png)

If you have any info that would help I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Should that `url` be an f-string?

Comment: I'm not sure lol that is why I'm asking. I didn't think it should be an f-string as i've not seen any examples with it as an f-string but I'm not sure. If it was a string then I would be curious how it would know where it input the variables into the url.

Comment: Well what do you expect `{subscriptionId}` to do in that string?

Comment: The issue that it is showing in debugging is something with this part

 `api_json = {keys: request.form[key] for key in keys}`

Comment: I would think that subscriptionId in that string would be sticking the `subscriptionId` variable there. or the key=value

Comment: Then it needs to be an f-string: `url = f'https://.../{subscriptionId}/...'`

Comment: I tried the `f string` but I'm still getting the error you see in the photo I attached. Although I do see that adding the `f string` did actually use my variables from the `request.form` which is cool. I wonder if I don't need the JSON if I just use the `f string` ? @chris

Comment: Okay so I did use the f string and I took out the JSON and it's gotten a step further. Now I'm getting the following error. 

`{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."}}`

Comment: That's a different question. Please post it separately. I'll post an answer about the f-string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't interpolate values in regular strings:

```py
url = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/...'
#                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Assuming you're using Python 3.6 or later, use an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to enable interpolation:

```py
url = f'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/...'
#     ^ here
```